# Text inside div not showing multiple white spaces between words

Tags: html, css

Div is not showing multiple white spaces in between strings

For Example:

This string `'New      Folder'` I would like to be displayed as 'New     Folder'

Comment: Ok ... now how exactly is the string 'New Folder' supposed to be displayed? Seems to me like this is the expected result?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

That is how html works. Whitespace is collapsed. Look at the way your question is displayed to see an example.

To work around this, wrap your text in a `<pre>` tag, or use `&nbsp;` instead of space characters

---

Or add `white-space:pre` to the CSS for the div.

Comment: yes - I was just coming back to the question to add that suggestion :) It doesn't work in IE 8 and earlier, though.

Comment: @anothershrubery - 牛逼! which means fantastic and awesome in chinese!

Answer (score 13):

You could also use CSS to add styling like a `<pre>` tag. Use

```
  div#where-you-want-the-whitespace {
      white-space: pre;
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Try:

> `white-space: pre-wrap;`

This does 2 things that can help others:

1. Keeps spaces as you want.
2. Wraps text so that if it is too long it remains clean inside a container.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is happening in html, just like you enter and it show same....

You need either to use simple html => **&nbsp**, or <**pre**> tag.... Or you can also assign variable to a '**span**' tag by some id... => **"span style='padding-left:20px'"**This line starts after some blank space at left "span"

@* because tag is not accepting here so thats why use,, "span" .