# Format a float to justify to the right

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have a table in my HTML and I want to put a float variable into a column. I also want this variable to justify itself to the right.

Currently, I am trying `{{ float|floatformat:2|rjust }}`, but it keeps throwing up a TemplateSyntaxError. Is it even possible to do this via the template system, or will I just have to use some CSS styling for this?

Comment: You are right: the template system renders the content, styling should be done with css.

Comment: @allcaps you seem to be right on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/):

> "{{ value|rjust:"10" }}"
>
> If value is Django, the output will be "____Django".

**EDIT**: If you do use this solution, be sure to surround the element with a `<pre>` tag because extra spaces are removed by your browser. Or [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151554/text-inside-div-not-showing-multiple-white-spaces-between-words) for info.

Comment: @Parker E. What error do you get? Could you check the debugger which line is raising the error?

Comment: It doesn't throw up an error. It just doesn't do the formatting. The text still appears to be left-justified.

Comment: @ParkerE. Could you try removing middle filter and leaving just this `{{ float|rjust:"10" }}`

Comment: hmm, I was just testing it and it seems to be working fine, could you inspect the element and clarify that spaces are not padded to the right of the value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164019/discussion-between-parker-e-and-laurynas-tamulevicius).

Comment: thanks for the `<pre>` hint. I feel dumb not to realize it on my own, LOL

Answer (score 0):

{{ value|rjust:"10" }} didn't work for me so I had to format the string before being passed to the HTML page.

I first right aligned the string with an arbitrary character:

amount.rjust(12, '$')

And then replace the character with "&nbsp;"

amount.replace('$', '&nbsp;')

Comment: I figured out that it didn't work maybe because I am sending a string to the Template, not a float.