# Spaces not shown in HTML

Tags: html

I have the following text stored in a MySQL database.

```
<p style='text-align: left;'><span style='font-size: 10px;'>Test</span><strong style='font-size: 10px;'><span style='color: red;'> red bold </span></strong><span style='font-size: 10px;'>text</span></p>
```

In a page it is read and displayed as

```
$htmlText = ... gets the above html from the database

<div id="text1" onclick="modalText(this)" style="border: 1px solid;">
    <?php echo $htmlText;?>
</div>
```

and I get this:

[image]

When I click on the div it opens a modal window where the text can be edited using tinyMCE and here it displays without the spacing issue.

[image]

Why do I get the initial spacing problem and how can I work around it?

Comment: use `&nbsp;` instead of space

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text inside div not showing multiple white spaces between words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151554/text-inside-div-not-showing-multiple-white-spaces-between-words)

Comment: Yes I could do that but if I am storing a lengthy string it seems that should be a better solution than replacing every space with &nbsp;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS to the element containing the text:

```css
element {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

> Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

Stack Snippet:

```css
div {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  foo     bar          baz
</div>
```

Comment: It helps with the spaces although I need to use pre-wrap for longer text. The problem with this solution is that it makes knocks out the vertical positioning of the text.